# MapState in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to store about 500 keys in MapState for each key in KeyedStream. I don't know how MapState works.

When i access MapState, i have to read all keys, then update one of them. Does MapState works efficiently here?

Answer (score 0):

When used with the `HashMapStateBackend`, `MapState` is a an in-memory hash map (inside a multi-versioned, concurrency-controlled hash map). When used with the `EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend`, each key/value pair in `MapState` is a separate key/value pair in a local RocksDB instance.

Note that `MapState` has a `keys` method that returns all of the keys, and an `iterator` method for iterating over all of the key/value pairs. But regardless of which state backend you choose, both of these operations are expensive.